# How to add queue in sending mails in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-mail

I already edited my **.env** to QUEUE_CONNECTION=database and tried to replace from send to queue. I also tried to add implements ShouldQueue to my **CertificatEmail** but not working. I don't know what's missing. 
**SendMail Controller**

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
    $users = StudentApplicants::whereIn("id", $request->ids)->get();

    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        $data = [
            'fname' => $user->users->first_name,
            'mname' => $user->users->middle_name,
            'lname' => $user->users->last_name,
            'gwa'  => $user->gwa,
            'sy'  => $user->school_year
        ];

        $qrcode = base64_encode(QrCode::format('svg')->color(128, 0, 0)->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')->generate($user->users->stud_num));
        $pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadView('admin.send-awardees-certificates.certificate', $data, array('qrcode' => $qrcode));
        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        Mail::to(config('mail.notification_recipient'))->queue(new CertificateEmail($user, $pdf));
    }
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Send email successfully. Refresh the page']);
}
```

**CertificateEmail** from mail

```
class CertificateEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public $pdf;
public $user;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($user, $pdf)
{
    $this->pdf = $pdf;
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    // return $this->view('view.name');

    return $this->from(env('info@gmail.com'))
        ->subject('Certificate from ABC EFG')
        ->view('email.certificate-email')
        ->attachData($this->pdf->output(), 'stock_report.pdf');
}
```

}

---

Answer (score 0):

Run these two queries in command

```
php artisan queue:table # creates a table for queued jobs

php artisan migrate # migrates the table
```

Then run

```
php artisan queue:work
```

In from env I think it doesn't write right please review it should be USER_EMAIL or something like that

Comment: How about creating jobs?

Comment: I already fix it by using jobs, but still having a problem in sending attachments though.